# Enforce a single NULL end date per foreign key value using an index

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, constraint

I want to implement a Check Constraint across a date range and foreign key.

I have a table created as:

- Primary Key
- Foreign Key
- DateStart
- DateEnd

The *ForeignKey* can appear many times in the table as long as there is a value in the *EndDate*. But there should only ever be one entry for the *ForeignKey* where the *DateEnd* is Null (the active version).

Apologies if this is simple, but I've been trying to use SQL Server GUI to put in an Constraint expression, but I can't get it to work.

Any help, or pointers to help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the provided answer solved your problem please consider [accepting the answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a unique filtered index.

Table setup.

```
create table dbo.OtherTable
(
  FK int primary key
);

create table dbo.YourTable
(
  PK int identity primary key,
  FK int references dbo.OtherTable(FK),
  DateEnd date
);
```

Add the unique index on `FK` filtered on `DateEnd is null`.

```
create unique index UX_YourTable_FK_DateEnd on dbo.YourTable(FK) 
  include (DateEnd)
  where DateEnd is null;
```

Add one row to `OtherTable`.

```
insert into dbo.OtherTable(FK) values(1);
```

Add a couple of rows to `YourTable`.

```
insert into dbo.YourTable(FK, DateEnd) values(1, '2001-01-01');
insert into dbo.YourTable(FK, DateEnd) values(1, null);
```

Add another row with a value in `DateEnd` will work just fine.

```
insert into dbo.YourTable(FK, DateEnd) values(1, '2001-01-01');
```

Add a second row with `null` in `DateEnd` will fail.

```
insert into dbo.YourTable(FK, DateEnd) values(1, null);
```

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 33 Cannot insert duplicate key row
>   in object 'dbo.YourTable' with unique index 'UX_YourTable_FK_DateEnd'.
>   The duplicate key value is (1).

[Create Filtered Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx)
[Create Unique Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx)

When scripting indexes from SSMS:

1. Make sure "Script Indexes" is True in the Advanced Scripting Options. It is default True if you script the entire database but False if you specify a specific table.
2. Also make sure the setting under "Tools / Options / SQL Server Object Explorer / Scripting" is set to "Script for server version 2008" (at least) otherwise the [filtering condition will be silently omitted](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/357475/ssms-scripting-filtered-index-stat-leaves-out-filter) (Connect bug report).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I did as you say and it seems to work, but I'm confused as to why when I get SQL Sever to generate a Script Task to recreate the table afterwards that the Filtered Index does not appear in the code. I would have assumed it should add this code to so it recreates the Table exactly.

Comment: @nytrex The filtered index definition will be left out if your script settings say to target SQL Server 2005 ([this tricked me before too](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/357475/ssms-scripting-filtered-index-stat-leaves-out-filter)). There is also a [bug that has been fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526911/ssms-table-designer-fails-to-correctly-script-filtered-index) and you may be affected. What is `SELECT @@VERSION;` output, and what is the build # in SSMS' Help > About?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand many thanks. the first link you provided was very useful. Once I made changes to the 'Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Table and View options > Script Indexes to TRUE  the Constraint now appears.